# Is there a standalone version of soapUI for Linux?

Tags: installation, package-management

I want to run soapUI on Ubuntu 11.10. If I am not able to install via the package manager, I'd prefer not to install at all, and instead run as a standalone application. Looking at the [soapUI download page](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui/4.5.0-beta1/) I can't figure out which download (if any) fulfills this criterion?

- soapui-4.5.0-Beta1-linux-bin.zip
- soapUI-x32-4_5_0-Beta1.sh

I'm guessing "bin" but I don't know for sure. Any clues?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Download the zip file. Then you just unzip the files into a directory somewhere. There is a sh file - you just need to make it executable and run that - from memory.

```
unzip soapui-*.zip
cd soapui-4.5.0-Beta1/bin/
chmod +x soapui.sh
./soapui.sh
```

Comment: Also you need 32bit Java to run it (if on 64bit system)

Comment: Not quite. If your using Oracle JDK, you'll need to uncomment a line from the soapui.sh to make it work, otherwise you'll get a gui related error.  Also, I run it just fine with a 64-bit JVM.

Answer (score 8):

Supposing that you don't have a GUI in your installation you can try from the command line simply using `wget` to download [Linux tarball](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release.html):

```
$ wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.eviware/soapuios/5.4.0/SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz
```

Then `ungzip` and `untar` the download archive:

```
$ gunzip SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz
$ tar xvf SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar
```

Now instead of start the UI of `SOAPUI` using `SOAPUI_HOME/bin/soapui.sh` you can use [`SOAPUI/bin/testrunner.sh`](https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/running-functional-tests.html) to run your projects without the UI.

Comment: url not found..

Comment: Did you check the soapui page link?... seems the new url is: `https://s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.eviware/soapuios/5.4.0/SoapUI-5.4.0-linux-bin.tar.gz`

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, there is no repository to be added to the sources, so SOAPUI cannot be installed through apt-get or Ubuntu package management. Some description is on https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/installing-soapui/installing-on-linux-or-unix.html . Resolution given by Trent is only option, but in reality, currently, you should **download just .sh file** (Linux installer) from https://www.soapui.org/downloads/latest-release.html which has approx. 130+MB and try following commands for 64bit:

```
$ sudo chmod +x SoapUI-x64-5.4.0.sh
$ ./SoapUI-x64-5.4.0.sh
```

or 32 bit:

```
$ sudo chmod +x SoapUI-x32-5.4.0.sh
$ ./SoapUI-x32-5.4.0.sh
```

(* scripts updated to version 5.4.0

Replace the name of the file according to the downloaded version of the SOAP UI.
Enjoy your testing!

Answer (score 3):

On a 64 bit operating system, use the zip file installer. The shell installer includes a 32 bit jvm.