# What is a simple, free SOAP client (GUI)?

Tags: software-recommendation, gui, client

On Windows I would use SoapUI, which can be run on Ubuntu either as a standalone application (see instructions on how in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113159/is-there-a-standalone-version-of-soapui-for-linux)) or as [an Eclipse plugin](http://www.soapui.org/IDE-Plugins/eclipse-plugin.html). Is there any other GUI available - perhaps something in a repository - for testing SOAP services?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can still use SOAPUI.

1. [Download the installation script](https://www.soapui.org/getting-started/installing-soapui/installing-on-linux-or-unix.html) and save it on the disk.
2. then either

   - from a terminal

     ```
     cd /path-to-directory-where-you-downlaod-it
     sudo chmod +x soapUI-x32-4_0_0.sh
     sudo ./soapUI-x32-4_0_0.sh
     ```
   - Or if you don't like command you can do it graphically:

     1. *Right-click* on the downloaded file, select *Properties*, go to the *Permissions* tab and *Allow to execute as a program*.

        [image]
     2. Once that is done double click on the **.sh** file and select '**Run in terminal**' or **Run**
3. Then follow step by step instructions to finish the installation.

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/py52r.png)

### Alternatives

- [**Membrane SOAP Client**](http://www.membrane-soa.org/soap-client/) is a generic SOAP client written in Java. It provides a dynamic form generator for SOAP requests.

  [image]

  [source](http://www.membrane-soa.org/soap-client/)
- You can use [jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)  a 100% pure Java application designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance. It was originally designed for testing Web Applications but has since expanded to other test functions. Jmeter is in the Ubuntu repositories.

  [getting started](https://github.com/ntt-pf-lab/openstack-jmeter/wiki/Getting-Started-with-Jmeter)

Comment: I accepted this answer, but I'm really hoping for some alternatives to SoapUI.

Comment: I think you prefer SOAPUI

Comment: Check the updated answer

Answer (score 1):

[Mooza](http://moozaapp.webs.com/) is the best alternative for a soap client tool. This is a web application which can be easily deployed on Tomcat/JBoss/Jetty etc.

Answer (score 0):

another eclipse OSS client for windows, mac and linux:

http://membrane-soa.org/downloads/soap-client.htm